# Windows forms not updating vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm having to work in a vb.net project and I have to add new textfields and labels to a form. But when I change the layout of the form in Visual Studio the form looks fine, but after compilation and moving to a testserver the form all gets jumbled together and label/textfields are all over the place, and some are missing.

Why does this happens and how can I fix it? I think it could have something to do with form languages but I'm not sure. Since on test server there is a way to change the language from the app between dutch and french.

[image: In visual studio]

[image: On test server]

Comment: it's probably due to different DPI, font type and size, between your machine and the server. Make sure the font is scaled the same, and set the font type and size in the application labels.

Comment: Ok will try doing this right away. Thank you

Comment: Remade the whole form wtih the same font and size and still having the same issue. The version on the test server keeps being a specific one

Comment: When I read your title, I was expecting a database update not being reflected in a form. Maybe a different title like "Form displaying incorrectly on different computer." Would get more results.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the the issue by compiling the code in visual studio 2010 instead of 2017. Thought i would give it a try since the application was initially developed in VS 2010 and it worked.